# In Datomic, why does using numbers in a db/ident name produce an Invalid Token error?

Tags: datomic

I have noticed that this produces an "Invalid Token" error:

```
{
  :db/id #db/id[:db.part/user]
  :db/ident :my.namespace/54
  ...
}
```

The problem is with using the number "54". It works fine if it is written:

```
{
  :db/id #db/id[:db.part/user]
  :db/ident :my.namespace/fifty-four
  ...
}
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such is the syntax of [EDN](https://github.com/edn-format/edn#symbols) (and Clojure in particular) for keywords:

> [...] Keywords follow the rules of symbols, except they can (and must) begin with : [...]

in particular:

> [...] Symbols begin with a non-numeric character and can contain alphanumeric characters and . * + ! - _ ? $ % & = < > [...]